# Difficult limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I try to calculate the following limit to calculate the constants `C[1]` and `C[2]`:

```
Assuming[Element[{v,n,u},Integers]&&n>0&&u>0&&v>0,
 Limit[2^(-(1/2)-5 I v) a^(-2 I v) (-1+2 a-2 I u)^(1/4 (1+2 n-2 
  I v)) (-1+2 a+2 I u)^(1/4 (1-2 n-2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) ((1- 
2 a)^2+4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1+2 n+2 I v)) (2^(6 I v) a^(2 I v) (-I 
u)^(2 I v) C[1] Hypergeometric2F1[-n,1/2+I v,1+2 I v,(8 a 
u)/((-1+2 a-2 I u) (I+2 u))]+E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1+2 a-2 I u)^(2 I 
v) (I+2 u)^(2 I v) C[2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2-I v,-n-2 I v,1-2 
I v,(8 a u)/((-1+2 a-2 I u) (I+2 u))]),a->0]]
```

Mathematica could not get the limit and it must be
    equal to

```
(2^(1 + I v) (u^2)^(-((I v)/2))
Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2, 1, 1 - I v, -4 u^2] 
Pochhammer[
 1 + 2 I v, n])/Pochhammer[1, n]
```

thanks anyway

Comment: Something to adjust: C[1] and C[2] appear in the LHS, but not in the RHS.

Comment: Substituting {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 2, n -> 1, u -> 1, v -> 1, a -> 0.01} in the difference between the expression under the limit and (2^(1 + I v) (u^2)^(-((I v)/2))
Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2, 1, 1 - I v, -4 u^2] 
Pochhammer[
 1 + 2 I v, n])/Pochhammer[1, n], one obtains 15676.7 + 11614.6 I.

Comment: C[1] and C[2] are the constant we need to calculate from the initial values a=0 and the derivate of f[a](integral) when a=0

Comment: Now the parameter a appeares in the LHS, but not in (2^(1 + I v) (u^2)^(-((I v)/2))
Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2, 1, 1 - I v, -4 u^2] 
Pochhammer[
 1 + 2 I v, n])/Pochhammer[1, n].

Comment: exactly when a tend to 0 the result is (2^(1 + I v) (u^2)^(-((I v)/2)) Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1/2, 1, 1 - I v, -4 u^2] Pochhammer[ 1 + 2 I v, n])/Pochhammer[1, n].

Comment: @capea explain how you got the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the term multiplying `C[2]` does not have a well-defined limit as $a\to0$. Let's take the concrete case $n=u=v=1$:

```
With[{n = 1, u = 1, v = 1},
  Limit[2^(-(1/2) - 5 I v) a^(-2 I v) E^(3 π v) (-1 + 2 a - 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 + 2 n + 6 I v)) (-1 + 2 a + 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(2 I v) ((1 - 2 a)^2 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 - I v, -n - 2 I v, 1 - 2 I v, (8 a u)/((-1 + 2 a - 2 I u) (I + 2 u))],
  a -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]]
```

> (-1 - 2 I) 2^(-(1/2) - 5 I) 5^(2 I) E^(3 π + 2 I Interval[{0, π}])

The `Interval` shows that this limit is ill-defined.

For other values of $\{n,u,v\}$ the problem is the same. I think this means that you will need to set `C[2] = 0`. You are then left only with the `C[1]` term, which for $a\to0$ is

```
2^(-(1/2) + I v) (-1 + 2 a - 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) *
(-1 + 2 a + 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) ((1 - 2 a)^2 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) *
Hypergeometric2F1[-n, 1/2 + I v, 1 + 2 I v, (8 a u)/((-1 + 2 a - 2 I u) (I + 2 u))] /.
a -> 0
```

> 2^(-(1/2) + I v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) (-1 + 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (1 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v))

This disagrees with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

We set

```
expr = 2^(-(1/2) - 5 I v) a^(-2 I v) (-1 + 2 a - 
      2 I u)^(1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) (-1 + 2 a + 
      2 I u)^(1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) ((1 - 2 a)^2 + 
      4 u^2)^(1/
       4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) (2^(6 I v) a^(2 I v) (-I u)^(2 I v) C[
       1] Hypergeometric2F1[-n, 1/2 + I v, 
       1 + 2 I v, (8 a u)/((-1 + 2 a - 2 I u) (I + 2 u))] + 
     E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1 + 2 a - 2 I u)^(2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(2 I v) C[
       2] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 - I v, -n - 2 I v, 
       1 - 2 I v, (8 a u)/((-1 + 2 a - 2 I u) (I + 2 u))]);
```

Now we can evaluate the expression when `a->0`

```
expr /. {a -> 0}


(* Out[]= 0^(-2 I v) 2^(-(1/2) - 5 I v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(
     1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
     1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) (1 + 4 u^2)^(
     1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) (0^(2 I v) 2^(6 I v) (-I u)^(2 I v) C[1] + 
       E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(2 I v) C[2])*)
```

On the other hand, decompose the expression in a series

```
exp1 = Series[expr, {a, 0, 1}] // Normal


(* -((2^(1/2 + I v) a n (-1 - 2 I u)^(1/4 + n/2 - (I v)/2) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
       1/4 - n/2 - (I v)/2) (1 + 4 u^2)^(-(1/4) + n/2 + (I v)/2) C[
       1])/((-I + 2 u) (I + 2 u))) + 
     2^(-(1/2) + I v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
      1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (1 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) C[1] + 
     a^(-2 I v) (2^(-(1/2) - 5 I v) E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(
         1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v) + 2 I v) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
         1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(
         2 I v) (1 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) C[2] + (
        2^(1/2 - 5 I v) a E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(
         1/4 + n/2 + (3 I v)/2) (-1 + 2 I u)^(-(3/4) - n/2 - (I v)/
          2) (-I u)^(-2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(
         2 I v) (1 + 4 u^2)^(-(1/4) + n/2 + (I v)/2) (-I n + 2 v) C[
         2])/(-I + 2 u))*)
```

Take the zero term

```
exp1 /. {a -> 0}

(*Out[]= 2^(-(1/2) + I v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(
  1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v)) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
  1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (1 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) C[1] + 
 0^(-2 I v) 2^(-(1/2) - 5 I v) E^(3 \[Pi] v) (-1 - 2 I u)^(
  1/4 (1 + 2 n - 2 I v) + 2 I v) (-1 + 2 I u)^(
  1/4 (1 - 2 n - 2 I v)) (-I u)^(-2 I v) (I + 2 u)^(
  2 I v) (1 + 4 u^2)^(1/4 (-1 + 2 n + 2 I v)) C[2]*)
```

In both cases, limit expressions contain `0^(-2 I v)`. It is possible that this is the reason why it is not calculated `Limit[expr,a->0]`.
Note that `exp1` contains `(a^(-2 I v))`, therefore when `a->0` there is no limit.

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more careful with this limit $a\to0$, at least for the part with `C[2]`.

Comment: @Roman I used Mathematica 12. Why should I be careful? :)